# UBER Api : How to know if the user is a rider or driver?

Tags: uber-api

We are creating an application for Uber Driver and we found that we can authenticate the driver using Drivers Api, but we found that Riders and Drivers use the same api endpoint.

So how to know if the user is an Uber Driver or Rider? and how to know if the driver is verified driver and all his documents are approved or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you authenticate your user - you have following endpoint available to get driver info: "**[GET /v1/partners/me](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/references/api/v1/partners-me-get)**".

The Profile endpoint returns the profile of the authenticated driver. A profile includes information such as name, email, rating, and activation status.

Similar endpoint to get rider info is: "**[GET /v1.2/me](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/me-get)**". The Rider User Profile endpoint returns information about the Uber user that has authorized with the application.

Comment: Does it require a full access to use this endpoint  "GET /v1/partners/me"?

Comment: In order to use "GET /v1/partners/me" endpoint, you will need full access to the Driver API scope "partner.accounts". Driver API is with limited access. You can apply for access to Driver API here: https://developer.uber.com/products/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, may I ask one more question please.

I saw Uber providing ready libraries for several programming language, Does Uber provides a library for .Net since we are building a Xamarin.Forms application?